# Is it possible to catch the response of search feature available in url

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to write automated screenshotter using puppeteer in node.js which will navigate to particular url.url have one faeture for search box which will give the information for desired query.If we get desired output screenshot is taken and saved to "success" folder but we didnt get any result (like no result found), i want screenshot in "failure" folder. Is It possible to record the response and segregate the screenshots.

Comment: quite vague question without a code example. I would downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can check html value and return value with page.evaulate() then you can use switch case according to incoming value and use page.screenshot() function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your question broken down to bits,

You are trying to,

- write automated screenshotter using puppeteer in node.js
- which will navigate to particular url.
- url have one feature for search box.
- which will give the information for desired query.

  - If we get desired output

    - screenshot is taken and saved to "success" folder
  - but we didnt get any result (like no result found),

    - i want screenshot in "failure" folder.

**Is It possible to record the response and segregate the screenshots?**
The answer is, **Yes**.

For example, it can be a simple google/yahoo/duckduckgo results **scraper** . Save screenshot depending on the result count.

You can use `.goto` to go to the page, `.$$` to check the results, `.screenshot` to take screenshot depending on the results.

Here is an example code to check if there is any result or not,

```
let results = !!await page.$("div > div > h3 > a");
// returns if there is any result in google search

let path;
if (results) {
   path = "success/mysuccessimage.png";
} else {
   path = "failed/myfailimage.png";
}

await page.screenshot({ path });
```

Since you did not share any code, no one will be able to help you. But I guess I answered your question. Now, you can implement it in a thousand ways, peace.